# Unable to restart customized Linux from Azure portal

Tags: linux, azure, cloud

I am new to Azure cloud.

Uploaded my customized Linux VM in VHD format into Azure.
I could deploy this VM on Azure. Portal gives message deployment is succeeded
Since my customized Linux does not have init.d scripts, 'waagent' is started not from init.d scripts.

Now when I click on 'Restart VM' on portal, my customized Linux does not reboot
Anyone know how Azure fabric reboots a VM. 
If any package is missing in my VM, I can add it

Thanks

Comment: recovery console, debug logs, see where the boot hangs.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to upload customized Linux VM VHD to Azure, we should prepare this VHD then upload it to Azure.

For example, if we upload ubuntu VHD to Azure, we should do next steps:

1.Replace the current repositories in the image to use Ubuntu's Azure **repos**.
2.Update the operating system to the latest **kernel**
3.Modify the kernel **boot line** for Grub to include additional kernel parameters for Azure.
4.Ensure that the **SSH server** is installed and configured to start at boot time.
5.Install the Azure **Linux Agent**
6. deprovision the virtual machine and prepare it for provisioning on Azure.

More information about prepare VHD, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json).

To fix this issue, we can download this VHD and open it with Hyper-v then prepare it again, and install Azure Linux Agent on it.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.